# flutter secure storage how to store bearer token?

Tags: json, flutter, rest, token

I try to store bearer access token to flutter secure storage. But I only able to access to body part details.
i print jsonDecode(res.body) i can get all the details. but i write await storage.write(key: "token", value: data["access_token"]); i get null return.

How can I access to Body>Data > Accesstoken to get token and storage into secure storage?

```
                         var data = jsonDecode(res.body);
                         
                                            
                          await storage.write(key: "token", value: data["access_token"]);
                        
                         
                        
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                              context, SlideRightRoute(page: ooww()));
                          break;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHZcT.png)

Comment: What if you add `print(data['access_token'])` before save it?

Comment: i get  null return @MiftakhulArzak

Comment: isn't it data["data"]["access_token"]?

Comment: tq problem solve with data["data"]["access_token"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is inside the key data. So you have to use

```
var data = jsonDecode(res.body);              
await storage.write(key: "token", value: data['data']["access_token"]);
```

Comment: tq, your answer is correct but i cant upvote due to low reputation.

Comment: You can accept the answer. Near my answer you will see a tick mark. If you click on it. That becomes an accepted answer